# Hive query cli works, same via hue fails

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hue, beeline

I have a weird issue with hue (version 3.10).

I have a very simple hive query:

```
drop table if exists csv_dump;
create table csv_dump row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' location '/user/oozie/export' as select * from sample;
```

- running this query in the hive editor works
- running this query as an oozie workflow command line works
- running this query command line with beeline works
- running this query via an oozie workflow from hive fails

Fail in that case means:

- drop and create are not run, or at least do not have any effect
- a prepare action in the workflow will be executed
- the hive2 step in the workflow still says succeeded
- a following step will be executed.

Now I did try with different users (oozie and ambari, adapting the location as relevant), with exactly the same success/failure cases.

I cannot find any relevant logs, except maybe from hue:

```
------------------------

Beeline command arguments :
             -u
             jdbc:hive2://ip-10-0-0-139.eu-west-1.compute.internal:10000/default
             -n
             oozie
             -p
             DUMMY
             -d
             org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
             -f
             s.q
             -a
             delegationToken
             --hiveconf
             mapreduce.job.tags=oozie-e686d7aaef4a29c020059e150d36db98

Fetching child yarn jobs
tag id : oozie-e686d7aaef4a29c020059e150d36db98
Child yarn jobs are found - 
=================================================================

>>> Invoking Beeline command line now >>>

0: jdbc:hive2://ip-10-0-0-139.eu-west-1.compu> drop table if exists csv_dump; cr 
eate table csv_dump0 row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines termina 
ted by '\n' location '/user/ambari/export' as select * from sample;

<<< Invocation of Beeline command completed <<<

 Hadoop Job IDs executed by Beeline: 


<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<


Oozie Launcher, capturing output data:
=======================
#
#Thu Jul 07 13:12:39 UTC 2016
hadoopJobs=


=======================

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://ip-10-0-0-139.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/oozie/oozie-oozi/0000011-160707062514560-oozie-oozi-W/hive2-f2c9--hive2/action-data.seq

Oozie Launcher ends
```

Where I see that beeline is started, but I do  not see any mapper allocated as I do command line.

Would anybody have any idea of what could go wrong?

Thanks,
Guillaume

Comment: This is the `stdout` you have provided here. Did you check the `stderr` logs. I guess, the MR job information/logs comes into the `stderr` section.

Comment: The stderr does not provide anything interesting at all, just connecting/connected/closed connection to the hive server 2 url. Nothing more relevant anywhere in /var/log/whatever.

Comment: Did you add new lines in the sql script file?

Comment: @Romain indeed there were no newlines and adding some fixed the issue. I you write this as an answer, not only a comment, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @romain in the comments, new lines need to be added in the sql script. Then all is good.

Comment: Thanks @Romain! I have been fighting this problem for many days with a script that contains a single sentence.  I added a new line at the end of the sentence and it worked. So... you need to add new lines after each sentence, even the last sentence of the script.